# Evaluating a tricky integral using Cauchy's integral formula.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I have recently learned how to compute complex integrals using the Cauchy integral formula but I have come across one with an nth power involved where I am unsure how to proceed. The integral is:

$$\int_{C_1(i)}\frac{z^3}{(z-i)^n}dz$$

For reference, my definition provided for the Cauchy integral formula is:

$$\bbox[yellow]
{f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2πi}\oint_{C_r(\hat z)}{\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}}dz
}
$$

EDIT: Have asked my lecturer and apprently it is possible to use Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives but I have had no luck, any help?

Comment: the integral is equal to $$ 2\pi i D^{n-1}z^{3}$$

Comment: @JoseGarcia Can you show some working? Unfortunately a simple answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's formula for derivatives?

Comment: @Mathlover Yes but I am not permitted to use it for this question, only the definition.

Comment: Are you permitted to use Laurent's Theorem?  Specifically the part about $c_n = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using $$\frac{z^3}{(z-i)^n}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\frac{z^3}{z-w}\bigg|_{w=i}$$

Comment: $z^3 = (z-i+i)^3=(z-i)^3+3i(z-i)^2+3i^2(z-i)+i^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $f(z)=z^3$ is entire. So it is differentiable on $D_{1+\epsilon}(i)$.

Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives tells us that for all $\zeta \in D_{1+\epsilon}(i)$
$$f^{(n-1)}(\zeta)=\frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i}\int_{C_1(i)}\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-i)^n}$$

Hence 
$$\int_{C_1(i)}\frac{z^3dz}{(z-i)^n}=\frac{2\pi i f^{(n-1)}(i)}{(n-1)!}$$

Hopefully that is enough for you to determine the integral for various values of $n$

Edit: Set $n'=n-1$ then Cauchy's formula for derivatives states:
$$f^{(n')}(\zeta)=\frac{n'!}{2\pi i}\int_{C_1(i)}\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-i)^{n'+1}}$$
Work out this integral and then replace $n'$ with $n-1$ in the final answer

Comment: Yeah I came to this result but I wasn't sure if you could change the formula from $f^n(i)$ to $f^{n-1}(i)$. I will try this now.

Comment: You could just set $n'=n-1$ then you have exact Cauchy's formula in terms of $n'$ and after applying it, just substitute in for your $n$

Comment: Do you think you can try this for me? I understand what you mean but can't apply it. Sorry for being difficult.

Comment: Sure, please see edit

Comment: @pureundergsgrad Should it not be $\frac{n!}{2πi)$ at before the integral, instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right. I edited in the factorial part